# How can I keep label string length from affecting size of a Polar Area chart?

Tags: charts, chart.js

Trying to implement this chart:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart

If I change the labels to something longer then the main graph gets resized. The longer the label string length, the smaller the graph. Is there a way to prevent the labels from affecting the graph size? Or to separate the labels from the graph itself?

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gcvat2nr/

```
var data = {
  datasets: [{
      data: [
          11,
          16,
          7,
          3,
          14
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
          "#FF6384",
          "#4BC0C0",
          "#FFCE56",
          "#E7E9ED",
          "#36A2EB"
      ],
      label: 'My dataset' // for legend
  }],
  labels: [
      "Red",
      "Green",
      "Yellow",
      "Grey",
      "Blue"
  ]
};
```

Try changing the labels to a long string and the graph will become tiny.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the only way to prevent this is to dynamically create the tooltips. I initialize the labels to be something small, like "a", then in the options parameter use the callbacks to generate the tooltip content. This way, the graph is originally rendered with short strings as labels (they won't show) and you can generate longer labels/tooltips if needed.